# getIntent() does not exist despite inheriting from Activity class?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have an application that has a camera as one activity. While I am in this camera activity, I want to press a button. This button will take a screenshot, and send the screenshot to another activity where I can do stuff on it.

So far I am sending the screenshot via Intents, and adding the screenshot in a bundle. However, upon trying to extract the bundle in my second activity, it keeps telling me that getIntent() does not exist in this context.

I've done some Googling and it seems like the primary issue is that the classes don't extend from Activity. However, both of my classes do! And there don't seem to be any other solutions on the internet.

Here is the relevant code in my main class:

```
namespace EmuCvApp.MotionDetect
{
    [Activity(Label = "MotionDetectionActivity")]
    public class MotionDetectionActivity : Activity, CameraBridgeViewBase.ICvCameraViewListener2, View.IOnTouchListener
    {

     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

          Button createRodi = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.add_rodi);
            createRodi.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                Android.Graphics.Bitmap bmp = null;
                Mat tmp = mRgba;

                try
                {
                    bmp = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(tmp.Cols(), tmp.Rows(), Android.Graphics.Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
                    Utils.MatToBitmap(tmp, bmp);
                    savePhotoToSD(bmp);
                    Intent createIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(CreateNewRodiActivity));
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.PutParcelable("screenshot", bmp);
                    createIntent.PutExtras(bundle);
                    StartActivity(createIntent);


                }
                catch (CvException t) { }

            };
```

And here is the code in the class that is being called:

```
     [Activity(Label = "CreateNewRodiActivity")]
    class CreateNewRodiActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
             Bitmap scrnshot = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("BitmapImage");
        }
    }
```

Note that there is code in the first activity that is missing - it's just irrelevant to what is going on here.

I basically just want to be able to get rid of this compilation error. Even if I try something like Intent intent = getIntent(), it still fails on me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the Xamarin.Android c# equivalent `Bitmap scrnshot = Intent.Extras.GetParcelable("BitmapImage"); as Bitmap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most Android `get*` and `set*` methods are mapped to C# properties in Xamarin.  So `getIntent` in java becomes just `Intent` in C#

As @Nick suggests,

```
Bitmap scrnshot = Intent.Extras.GetParcelable("BitmapImage"); as Bitmap
```